I am unable to access variables set in the karate feature file during gatling session
I'm unable to access variables set in the karate feature file during gatling session*
Error Msg:02:35:57.473 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-10' crashed on session Session(CreateSubscription,1,1725397536872,Map(orderId1 -> mqj5fjxy, attempts -> 0, customerId ->3432423, requestStartTime -> 1725397536894, 2dd34680-e360-4aaa-aaf9-f325f4e8f461 -> 0),0,OK,List(ExitOnCompleteLoopBlock(attempts), GroupBlock(List(Create and Confirm Subscription),1725397536894,0,OK), ExitOnCompleteLoopBlock(2dd34680-e360-4aaa-aaf9-f325f4e8f461)),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$485/1658512704@639d7e27), forwarding to the 
next onejava.util.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'subscription_confirmed' is defined    at io.gatling.core.session.SessionAttribute.as(Session.scala:46)

i want to set subscription_confirmed  variable as true in karate feature file and access in gatling session.
**
Subscription.feature

Feature: create Subscription feature

  Background: Obtain test data for the scenario
      * def envName = karate.env
      * def token = “1234”
      * header Authorization = 'Bearer '+token   
      * def CID = __gatling.customerId
      * def orderId = __gatling.orderId1
      * print 'Captured orderId:', orderId
      
  

    Scenario: CreateSubscription
            
          * def createPayLoad = read('classpath:tests/payLoads/CreateSubscriptions_testdata/TestData_Subscriptions.json')
          * url “endurl”
          * path  createSubscription
          And headers {correlationId: #(correlational), env: '#(envName)'}
          * createPayLoad.orderItem[0].id = orderId
          * createPayLoad.relatedParty[0].id = CID
          * request createPayLoad
          * method post
          * status 200
    

 getSubscriptionWithValidation.feature
            
            Feature: Get Subscription   
              Scenario: GetSubscription
            * def getToken = call read('classpath/test/generateToken.feature')
            * def token = getToken.response.access_token
            * header Authorization = 'Bearer '+token
            * url 'https://rest.sandbox.com/v8/subscriptions/123'
            * method get
            * status 200  
            * And match response.data[0].custom_fields.product_id__c == 123
            * def subscription_confirmed = response.data[0].custom_fields.product_instance_id__c ==  123 
            *   And karate.set('subscription_confirmed' ,subscription_confirmed )

Gatling scripts:
package performance

import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class PerformanceRunner extends Simulation {
  
  val protocol = karateProtocol()
  protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("scenario")

  System.setProperty("telus.appName", "Performance")
  System.setProperty("KongFlag.value", "true")
  System.setProperty("useToken.value", "true")
  System.setProperty("karate.appName", "appname")

  val cidfeeder = csv("CustomerID.csv").circular

  val createSubscription = scenario("CreateSubscription")
    .repeat(1) {
      feed(ecidfeeder)
        .exec { session =>
          println(session("customerId").as[String])
          session
        }
        .exec(karateFeature("classpath:performance/Subscription.feature"))
        
.exec(session => {
          var confirmed = false
          var attempts = 0
          val maxAttempts = 10
          val pollInterval = 1000 // 5 seconds

          while (!confirmed && attempts < maxAttempts) {
            // Polling GET API
            exec(karateFeature("classpath:services/Zoura/getSubscriptionWithValidation.feature"))
            // Check if the response is confirmed
            if (session.contains("subscription_confirmed")) {
              confirmed = true
            } else {
              attempts += 1
              Thread.sleep(pollInterval)
            }
          }
          if (!confirmed) {
            // Handle failure, if needed
            session.markAsFailed
          }

          session
        })
    }

  setUp(
    createSubscription.inject(rampUsers(1) during (10 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )
}

Used Gatling version :0.9.4

impossible for anyone to troubleshoot this without working code, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

I updated working code , could you please help me to resolve this issue.

that doesn't work for me, hope someone else here can help, all the best

You are setting the value correctly in the feature file, I think you are just accessing it incorrectly in the scala/gatling file, try this inside of session block to access it.
.exec(session => {
//capture the set value from the karate feature
val subscription_confirmed = session("subscription_confirmed").as[String]
println(s"Captured value from feature file is : $subscription_confirmed")
session })

if subscription_confirmed is actually a boolean value, you can change the as[String] to as[Boolean] to get back a proper boolean
